# Android Async, Handler or Timer?

Tags: android, timer, android-asynctask, handler

Every 5 seconds, I want to call my webservice and get text (not images), then display it in my ImageAdapter.  What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends if you want to use a different thread or not. Do you want the user to be able to interact with the application on the UI Thread while the images are downloading? If so, then I would definitely use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) with a small [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) (`style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"`)

If you don't care about threading then what @inazaruk said.

**Edit:** the truth is most modern apps that retrieve data from a web service will use an AsyncTask with a discreet little loader in the corner just to let the user know it's updating.

**Edit 2:** here's an example of using a TimerTask to run something every 5 seconds. The key is the `runOnUiThread()`. **There may be better ways to tie all the elements together** but this accurately portrays all the pieces.

```
myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            CallWebService();
        }

    }, 0, 1000);
}

private void CallWebService()
{
    this.runOnUiThread(fetchData);
}

private Runnable fetchData = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      asyncTask.execute();
    }
};
```

Comment: Ill add this as an update: What I am getting from the webservice is actually text, not an image.

Comment: Do you know If I can use the java timer class to run AsyncTask every 5 seconds?

Comment: @Raptrex: `Timer` is specifically for `TimerTask`, although it isn't that hard to make your own timer implementation in case you wanna use `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Would I use a Handler to call my AsyncTask every 5 seconds?

Comment: who is inazaruk and what did [s]he say?

Answer (score 8):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    final Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            callWebservice();
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 5000);
```

Comment: This is so definitely the right answer.  The only thing is that the run method  should probably re-schedule itself, by invoking postDelayed again.  Upvoted

Answer (score 0):

You should call asynctask inside the application main thread.  Asynctask can't be called in a background thread.